# How to remove nested key in Dart Programming Language

Tags: flutter, dart

Code block below is show how to remove 'firstName' key nested key inside 'nama' key.

What I want ask is

is any more efficient way to remove firstName key than code below ?

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> biodata = {};
biodata['nama'] = {
  'firstName' : 'Andrean',
  'lastName': 'tama',
};
Map<String, dynamic> name = biodata['nama'];
name.remove('firstName');
biodata['nama'] = name;
print(biodata['nama']['lastName']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to call `bioData['nama'].remove('firstName')` directly, don't need to create a copy of it. The code should look like this :

```
 Map<String, dynamic> biodata = {};
biodata['nama'] = {
  'firstName' : 'Andrean',
  'lastName': 'tama',
};
biodata['nama'].remove('firstName');
print(biodata['nama']);
```